# Dynamically displaying total amount of services selected using VBA - Shopping Cart

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of Service providers who offer certain services. Similar services can be also offered by various Service providers. i am facing challenge to display the amount based on services selected by the users. There are 3 tables.

1. Table 1  - Services added to the cart ( User can add qty) [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTm5M.png]
2. Table 2 -  Service provider related to the categories added in the cart - challenge is to show the total prices.
   [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXLFL.png]
3. Table 3 - Raw data with prices mentioned by service providers.

[image]

Until now, i have just added table 1 and table 2 into array and now it needs to matched to table 3

```
    Sub Button5_Click()

Set customer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CUSTOMER")
Set provider = Worksheets("PROVIDER_SETTINGS")

i = 0


NumSP = customer.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Rng = "I1:I" & NumSP
j = NumSP - Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(customer.Range(Rng))


NumService = customer.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Rng = "E1:E" & NumService
k = NumService - Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(customer.Range(Rng))

Dim ServiceProvider() As String  ' declare array for service provider
Dim Service() As String
On Error Resume Next
  ReDim ServiceProvider(0)
  ReDim Service(0)

'service providers inserted into array
 For x = 3 To j + 2
    sp = customer.Cells(x, 9).Value
    ServiceProvider(i) = sp
    i = i + 1
   ReDim Preserve ServiceProvider(i)

Next
c = 0

'services  inserted into array
 For y = 3 To k + 2
    noservice = customer.Cells(y, 5).Value
    Service(c) = noservice
    c = c + 1
    ReDim Preserve Service(c)
Next


Set Arg1 = provider.Range("H2:H100")
Set Arg2 = provider.Range("B2:B100")
Set Arg3 = provider.Range("C2:C100")
Set Arg4 = provider.Range("I2:I100")

pir = 3

For Pi = 0 To UBound(ServiceProvider)

Totalsum = 0

For pj = 0 To UBound(Service)

Count_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, ServiceProvider(Pi), Arg3, Service(pj), Arg4, "Y")
Totalsum = Totalsum + Count_1
Next
customer.Cells(pir, 11).Value = Totalsum
pir = pir + 1

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: So what exactly are you having problems with? What exactly is your question - what are you asking?

Comment: Challenge is to populate the " Total Amount " in Table 2 based on the quantities defined in Table 1. I have modified the code and now the sum comes up but still not able to figure out how to multiply with the quantities.

Comment: Code Modified - Sum comes out in the last step but without considering the quantities defined.

Comment: `*` is the multiplication operator - Perhaps `TotalSum * <your reference to quantities value>`

Comment: It has to be done dynamically based on the values in the arrays. so there is a bit more than * operator

Comment: Ah I see.. I'll take a further look. Also, just an FYI for future code *(keep in mind there are not set rules for this)*, consider using descriptive variable names rather than single letter fill ins. When you are debugging your own code, or in places like SO, it can be difficult and time consiming to understand and/or work out what `pi` or `pj` are representing, for example.

Comment: Sure @SamuelEverson for the advice.. will keep it in mind for the future code. Could solve the problem by adding 1 more array and then multiplying it in the last step. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Button5_Click()

Set customer = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CUSTOMER")
Set provider = Worksheets("PROVIDER_SETTINGS")

i = 0


NumSP = customer.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Rng1 = "I3:I" & NumSP
j = NumSP - Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(customer.Range(Rng1))


NumService = customer.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
Rng2 = "E3:E" & NumService
k = NumService - Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(customer.Range(Rng2))

Dim ServiceProvider() As String  ' declare array for service provider
Dim Service() As String
Dim qty() As Integer
On Error Resume Next
  ReDim ServiceProvider(0)
  ReDim Service(0)
  ReDim qty(0)

'service providers inserted into array
 For X = 3 To j + 2
    ServiceProvider(i) = customer.Cells(X, 9).Value
    i = i + 1
   ReDim Preserve ServiceProvider(i)

Next
c = 0

'services  inserted into array

 For y = 3 To k + 2
    Service(c) = customer.Cells(y, 5).Value
    c = c + 1
    ReDim Preserve Service(c)
Next
d = 0
For y = 3 To k + 2
    qty(d) = customer.Cells(y, 7).Value
    d = d + 1
    ReDim Preserve qty(d)
Next


Set Arg1 = provider.Range("H2:H100")
Set Arg2 = provider.Range("B2:B100")
Set Arg3 = provider.Range("C2:C100")
Set Arg4 = provider.Range("I2:I100")

pir = 3

For Pi = 0 To UBound(ServiceProvider)

Totalsum = 0

For pj = 0 To UBound(Service)

Count_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1, Arg2, ServiceProvider(Pi), Arg3, Service(pj), Arg4, "Y") * qty(pj)
Totalsum = Totalsum + Count_1
Next
customer.Cells(pir, 11).Value = Totalsum
pir = pir + 1

Next
End Sub
```